# Authentication.asmx gives error - Sharepoint 2010

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have added a reference to the authentication.asmx web service of my Sharepoint FBA site. I have the below code:

```
 Authentication auth = new Authentication();
            LoginResult lResult = auth.Login("******", "******");
```

The Login method throws an exception as shown below:

> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to
>   process request. --->
>   System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]:
>   Could not retrieve the IIS Settings. Parameter name: context    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustChannel.ReadResponse(Message
>   response)    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustChannel.Issue(RequestSecurityToken
>   rst, RequestSecurityTokenResponse& rstr)    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustChannel.Issue(RequestSecurityToken
>   rst)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurityContext.SecurityTokenForContext(Uri
>   context, Boolean bearerToken, SecurityToken onBehalfOf, SecurityToken
>   actAs, SecurityToken delegateTo, SPRequestSecurityTokenProperties
>   properties)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurityContext.SecurityTokenForFormsAuthentication(Uri
>   context, String membershipProviderName, String roleProviderName,
>   String username, String password, SPFormsAuthenticationOption options)
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPClaimsUtility.AuthenticateFormsUser(Uri
>   context, String userName, String password)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.Authentication.Login(String username,
>   String password)

I am using SQL Membership provider for setting up the FBA.

Comment: do you use the correct protocol for the webservice (http,https)?

Comment: @spoekes: yes, I have tried both. But, the result was always the same.

Comment: does it work with the SPClaimsUtility.AuthenticateFormsUser method from Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel namespace?

Comment: @spoekes: I am trying to develop a Windows Forms app that consumes the SharePoint service. I have tried the below code, but that also didn't work. I get the same error. Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("https://myserver/");
            ctx.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.FormsAuthentication;
            ctx.FormsAuthenticationLoginInfo = new FormsAuthenticationLoginInfo("*****", "*****");
            Web w = ctx.Web;
var lists = ctx.LoadQuery(w.Lists);          
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();